# How to find nodepool name from node in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

My requirement is to fetch the `nodepool` name from the node in AKS cluster.

I have been fetching `nodepool` name as `agentPool` name (given in below output response) but it seems to be incorrect.

What is the correct way to fetch the nodepool name for the corresponding node?

```
kubectl describe node aks-customName-234234234-vmss00011
```

```
Name:               aks-customName-234234234-vmss00011
Roles:              agent
Labels:             agentpool=customName
                    beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=Standard_D4s_v3
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=XXX
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=0
                    group=customName
                    kubernetes.azure.com/agentpool=customName
                    kubernetes.azure.com/cluster=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    kubernetes.azure.com/kubelet-identity-client-id=
                    kubernetes.azure.com/mode=user
                    kubernetes.azure.com/node-image-version=AKSUbuntu-XXXXXX
                    kubernetes.azure.com/os-sku=Ubuntu
                    kubernetes.azure.com/role=agent
                    kubernetes.azure.com/storageprofile=managed
                    kubernetes.azure.com/storagetier=Premium_LRS
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=aks-customName-234234234-vmss00011
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/role=agent
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/agent=
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=Standard_D4s_v3
                    storageprofile=managed
                    storagetier=Premium_LRS
                    topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone=
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=eastus2
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=0
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid:
                      {"disk.csi.azure.com":"aks-customName-234234234-vmss00011","file.csi.azure.com":"aks-customName-234234234-vmss00011"}
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 19 Aug 2022 14:25:23 -0500
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Addresses:
  Hostname:    aks-customName-234234234-vmss00011
  InternalIP:  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  8
  cpu:                            4
  ephemeral-storage:              129886128Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:                  0
  hugepages-2Mi:                  0
  memory:                         16009Mi
  pods:                           30
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-azure-disk:  8
  cpu:                            3860m
  ephemeral-storage:              119703055367
  hugepages-1Gi:                  0
  hugepages-2Mi:                  0
  memory:                         12597Mi
  pods:                           30
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 XXXXXXX
  System UUID:                XXXXXXX
  Boot ID:                    XXXXXXXX
  Kernel Version:             5.4.0-1086-azure
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://XXXXXX
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.9
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.9
ProviderID:                   azure:///subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/aks-customName-12312173-vmss/virtualMachines/4
Events:                          <none>
```

I donot see any attribute which matches the nodepool name. This is already running cluster and I have node informations as below for each node and nodepool list.

I need to group these nodes to the nodepool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the following commands which give the details of the node pool.

By using [az aks nodepool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
az aks nodepool show
```

This gives details for a node pool

By using [Kubectl](https://docs.giantswarm.io/ui-api/kubectl-gs/get-nodepools/)

```
kubectl gs get nodepools
```

This gives the list of node pools.